# angular-material-components/datetime-picker style not loading initially, but works after opening normal material date picker in Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker, angular-material-components

I'm using angular-material-components/datetime-picker version 16.. Following are the dependencies

```
"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^16.0.1",
"@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^16.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "~16.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/material": "~16.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
```

Initially Ngx-datetimepicker calendar popup not loading properly.. style issue is there.. after open one native material datepicker, Ngx-datetimepicker calendar popup will work correctly.. seems like style loading issue initially

[image]
After opening one normal material date picker, styles loading properly

[image]

Comment: I imagine your ngxMatDatetimePicker is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker), please, always you're asking about a library non standar is good indicate a link with the library. Check how you add the theme -I feel that works on prebuild-themes, but I'm in hurry to check it :(-

Comment: @Mohammed Safeer Dis you manage to resolve the issue?